# PostgreSQL UNIQUE for JOINed table

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, unique-constraint

Given the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE bom (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bom_item (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    bom_id_fk INT REFERENCES bom(id) NOT NULL,
    pcb_identifier varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Is it possible to place an `UNIQUE` constraint on `bom_item.pcb_identifier` for a certain `bom_id_fk` besides making them both `PRIMARY KEY`?.
The logic behind that is, that a `pcb_identifier` may only exist once in a certain BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want a unique constraint with two keys:

```
CREATE TABLE bom_item (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    bom_id_fk INTEGER REFERENCES bom(id) NOT NULL,
    pcb_identifier varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unq_pcb_identifier_bom_id_fk UNIQUE (pcb_identifier, bom_id_fk)
);
```

This will guarantee that at most one `pcb_identifier` per `bom_id_fk`.  Note that either key individually can be in the table multiple times.  It is the pair that is unique.

By the way, Postgres recommends replacing `serial` is `int generated always as identity`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint concerning the `serial`. I changed my setup (and the question) accordingly

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you would typically use a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) for this:

```
create unique index on bom_item(pcb_identifier) where(bom_id_fk = ?)
```

The question mark should be replaced with the value of `bom_id_fk` for which you want to enforce uniqueness of `pcb_identifier`.